# How to give value in select field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am making a select field. I google it find the we display different string and get different value in select box.

http://plnkr.co/edit/I9s79qGwqw0x6hGis0JX?p=preview

Now I am using json to form plugin from here

https://github.com/nimbly/angular-formly

when I apply all thing it gives value **1,2...**like that display name is different. I just want to change the value of select box how i could achieve this ?
Here is my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wcvh2AMxtopPmIwpJkfi?p=preview

```
$scope.formFields = [
    {
        //the key to be used in the result values {... "username": "johndoe" ... }
        key: 'username',

        //default value
        default: 'uberuser',
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Username',
        placeholder: 'johndoe',
        required: true,
        disabled: false, //default: false
        description: 'Descriptive text'
    },  {
    "key": "transportation",
    "type": "select",
    "label": "How do you get around in the city",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "Car"
        },
        {
            "name": "Helicopter"
        }
    ]
    }
];
```

I need If I select car it gives value "aadsasd".And when I select "Helicopter" gives values "psasdpasdpasd"

Answer (score 0):

In this plugin you can pass name and value both for option and it will generate value that you pass in option. This link https://github.com/nimbly/angular-formly/blob/master/src/directives/formly-field-select.html show you how this plugin creating select in form . it treated option as service so you can pass value like this

```
[
  {name: "red", value: "dgdsg"},
  {name: "white", value: "1dgsg"},
]
```

Comment: so is there any plugin in which display name and value is different

Comment: sorry for my bad. I am updating my answer. you can pass value as well in options.

Comment: can you please update by plubker please..i will be thankfull to you..?just add static select

Comment: I didn't find that you used plugin there. I am updating the code you given in question.

Comment: Nope I have same structure in my select but without plugin and working fine at my end.

Comment: mean you can generate form with json ..?

Comment: I used this plugin https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms..and make this plunker but don'y know how I will add select http://plnkr.co/edit/zCF4oZ5pNWbARaONSGtY?p=preview